# Tikz coordinates relative to a node, and outside it

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

Given a rectangular node `X` I have access to the coordinates `(X.north)`, `(X.east)` and the like.  However, I want to be able to draw two sides of a right-angled triangle on top of the node.  For example, if the node's top left and top right coordinates were `(0,3)` and `(2,3)` then I want to draw `(0,3) -- (1,4) -- (2,3)`.

In other words:

```
\draw (X.north west) -- <what goes here?> -- (X.north east);
```

How do I obtain my middle point using only the node itself?  The best I can do is

```
\draw (X.north west) -- ([shift={(X.north)}] X.north)-- (X.north east);
```

but that seems a little clumsy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's what the `calc` library is for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (X) {X node};
\draw (X.north west) -- ($(X.north west)!cos(45)!45:(X.north east)$) -- (X.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax is as follows:

`($(A)!<fraction>!(B)$)` referst to the point that lies `<fraction>` of the way along the line from `(A)` to `(B)`. `($(A)!0.5!(B)$)` would refer to the midpoint of the connecting line, `($(A)!0!(B)$)` refers to `(A)`, and `($(A)!1!(B)$)` refers to `(B)`. If the number is greater than 1 or less than 0, the path is extrapolated.

The syntax `($(A)!<fraction>!<angle>:(B)$)` refers to the point that lies `<fraction>` of the way along the line from `(A)` to `(B)` after that line has been rotated around `(A)` by `<angle>` degrees.

For a right-angled triangle, we know that if the angle between the hypotenuse and the adjacent side is 45°, the length of the adjacent side is cos(45)*h.

Similarly for other angles:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, outer sep=0pt] (X) {X node};
\foreach \angle in {15,30,...,75}{
    \draw [red!\angle!blue] (X.north west) -- ($(X.north west)!cos(\angle)!\angle:(X.north east)$) -- (X.north east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much - I think this answer will suit my needs best.

Answer (score 5):

Use the fact that a rectangle triangle having the hypotenuse as diameter of a circle has its other vertex on the circle, and use the `intersections` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle,minimum size=2cm] (X) {};
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path[name path=circle] let \p1=(X.north west), \p2=(X.north east) in 
  (X.north) circle (0.5*\x2-0.5*\x1);
\path[name path=line] (X.north) -- (60:3cm);
\draw[name intersections={of=circle and line,by={a}}] (X.north west) -- (a) -- (X.north east);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle,minimum size=2cm] (X) {};
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path[name path=circle] let \p1=(X.north west), \p2=(X.north east) in 
  (X.north) circle (0.5*\x2-0.5*\x1);
\foreach \i/\colo in {40/green,60/red,90/cyan,120/magenta}
{
\path[name path=line\i] (X.north) -- (\i:3cm);
\draw[name intersections={of=circle and line\i,by={a\i}},draw=\colo] (X.north west) -- (a\i) -- (X.north east);
}
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever - and a nice illustration of some Euclidean geometry!  However, I think Jake's answer below will be my preferred option.  But thank you for your time and trouble!

Comment: @Jake good suggestion. I've added the environments to my answer. Thanks!